# How to generate numerical relative waveforms representing gravitational wave strain for different masses?

Tags: general-relativity, simulations, computational-physics, gravitational-waves, ligo

I have read in many sources that Numerical relativity produces a general solution for the waveforms which are to be expected by LIGO data to identify the different masses which are observed .

Can anyone tell me how to perform numerical relativity to generate waveforms for any two given set of masses ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are specialized codes such as [the SpEC](https://www.black-holes.org/code/SpEC.html) (and others). The easiest way to learn how to use these would be to join a research program with numerical relativity experts.

There are many precalculated waveforms produced by such codes also available for use such as in the [SXS catalog](https://data.black-holes.org/waveforms/catalog.html).

In addition, there are many models which can be used to generate gravitational waveforms, which are derived from post-newtonian theory and/or fits to numerical relativity simulations. Many of these can be produced by the [PyCBC package](http://github.com/ligo-cbc/pycbc). There are some interactive examples that one [can try in the browser](https://notebooks.azure.com/nitz/libraries/pycbc).